# Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ with $x_1, \ldots , x_n$ are vectors such that the $T(x_i)$ are independent, then the $x_i$ are independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ and $x_1, \ldots , x_n$ are vectors such that $T(x_i)$ are independent, then the $x_i$ are independent for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

My attempt:

If I set $c_1T(x_1) + \cdots + c_nT(x_n) = 0$ then by linearity
$T(c_1(x_1) + \cdots + c_n(x_n)) = 0$ and by independece all the $c_i = 0$. Not sure how to conclude that the $x_i$ are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just going about it backwards: if $c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n=0_V$ for some numbers $c_i$, then
$$\begin{align*}
T(c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n)&=T(0_V)\\
c_1T(x_1)+\cdots+c_nT(x_n)&=0_W
\end{align*}$$
which implies that $c_1,\ldots,c_n=0$ since the vectors $T(x_1),\ldots,T(x_n)$ are independent in $W$.

Comment: @Ok So I started with the wrong initial assumption thanks!